# What is the average temperature in the luggage hold of a passenger plane?

Tags: temperature

I am asking this seemingly odd question, as we'll have to transport some medicine in our luggage and it's supposed to be stored at temperatures between `-8C` and `+2C`. I'm not sure, if airport security will allow this to pass if this is in a cooling box as hand-luggage, although, in my opinion there shouldn't be a problem, as the ampules are `4 x 1 ml` and I have a prescription (however, the cooling box will probably be treated as partially liquid containing).

Your advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered asking the airline? The temperature is not likely to be the major issue. That being said, I suspect the temperature is close to cabin temperature.

Comment: the [TSA allows](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/medically-necessary-liquids-gels-and-aerosols) you to bring medicine in your carry on luggage, including ice packs to keep them at temperature.

Comment: I believe this question is better on Travel.SE

Comment: I am inclined towards this being **related** to aviation as it talks about something related airplanes. Although this question has already been [asked](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22604/12615).

Comment: @erich The asker's profile gives their location as the UK and the question doesn't mention travelling to the US. As such, there's no indication that what the TSA allows is in any way relevant.

Comment: If you look at the actual question here - what is the typical temperature in the luggage hold of an airliner? - then I think this is indeed on-topic and can be clearly answered. Everything about the TSA, security, liquids, country of travel etc. is actually irrelevant to the basic point about temperature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been asked on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22604/12615).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to an A320 pilot quoted in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22604/will-my-checked-luggage-freeze-in-the-airplane/22609#22609) on travel.SE (and see [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39113/what-is-the-average-max-temperature-of-an-airplane-cargo-hold) too), the temperature can be 7C at the low end but potentially above 18C if animals are being transported. Therefore, if you want to transport something in the hold that needs to be kept at a specific temperature range you would need to check with the airline about how to do that.