# Temperature of airplane while flying?

Tags: temperature

When the air-plane reaches to the altitude of about 12,000 m or so, the airplane's outside cover is very cold due to the air temperature or very hot due to the friction? Or it depends on different parts of the airplane?

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23747/what-is-the-typical-temperature-of-an-airliners-hull-during-flight