# What type of variation in temperature does the wing undergo?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-systems, aerospace-materials

Generally what is temperature variation does the wing of the commercial aircraft like A380 undergo , flying at mach speed of 0.8 and how does it affect the aircraft other than icing , what type of literature can one go through to study the temperature effects on aircraft

Comment: Related: [What is the typical temperature of an airliner's hull during flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23747/3201)

Answer (score 1):

The temperature rise that is caused by flying at high subsonic/transonic speeds is approximately 40 degrees Celsius. But this happens only at the stagnation point (near the leading edge). Ref: aerodynamics text books.

The A380 and other airliners experience -55 to -60 degrees Celsius during cruise at altitude. Ref: aerodynamics (properties of the atmosphere)

On the ground they may experience up to 60 degrees Celsius of air temperature and with the sun radiation the surface temperature can rise up to approx. 80-90 °C. Depending on color and geographic location on earth. Ref: hard experience :) and Environment control system Analysis.

Comment: 90°C on the ground? That's only 10°C below water boiling point! Air temperature at 60°C at ground level, yes but this is [very exceptional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_weather_records#Highest_temperatures_ever_recorded).

Comment: Ive given the extremes, but they are quite usual for some regions in the world.